# Interaction between C and R

Tags: r

I have naive questions to ask:

1) When I want to call C in R, I have to write some C code. But sometimes I have to call a function which is written in R by myself, can I call that function in the C function?

2) If 1) is feasible, then if I use a function written in R repeatedly for 1000 times for a loop, will this speed up by using C to call this function to do the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well put question. A quick take:

1. Yes you can. It is (as so many things) possible yet a little tedious with the C-based API that R offers -- but (in our opinion at least) much easier with the C++ layer we put on top via [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html)
2. That is the critical point. If the R code is the bottleneck, it remains the bottleneck when you call it from C or C++ as *it does not matter where it is called from*. What matters is its relative speed.

The rcpp-devel list (links are on [Rcpp page](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html)) has a lot of related discussions; you can also find a lot here on SO under the `[rcpp]` tag.

Comment: Then basically if people want to gain the speed, they will not call R functions in the C function they want to call in R, right? Now here is the next question: is it tedious to do matrix operation in C? and will that be fast in C?

Comment: What I usually suggest is to (if you must) call one or a few R functions that are hard or tedious to replaces -- and to concentrate on replacing the "core" part of your computation with a C++ core.  Rcpp makes that approach pretty easy, and we have gotten really nice speed gains.

Comment: Yes and yes: tedious and fast. Have a look at RcppArmadillo though: easy to use, well documented, and still *very fast*.  I have a number of blog posts and examples which Google should find for you.

Comment: For matrix operation, fortran might be a little bit more friendly. Thus you need to call Fortran in R though.